# PHP arrays conversion and merging

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'Level' (length=5)
  1 => string 'Sub' (length=3)
  2 => string 'Item' (length=4)
```

And now I want to convert this array into this:

```
array (size=1)
  'Level' => 
    array (size=1)
      'Sub' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Item' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
```

Then I want to "merge" this "converted" array with this array:

```
array (size=1)
  'Level' => 
    array (size=1)
      'Sub' => 
        array (size=1)
          'AnotherItem' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
```

The result should look like this:

```
array (size=1)
  'Level' => 
    array (size=1)
      'Sub' => 
        array (size=2)
          'Item' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'AnotherItem' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
```

I also want to have ability to "merge" this result with another "converted" array.
I tried now for more than two hours to find a solution by myself, but now my brain is crashed -.-

Thanks for all help in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code.

Comment: Practically, i tried nothing. I just can't imagine the way how exactly thats works.

Comment: Well, then you need to read up on arrays in PHP and try something first. There are tons of examples out there. We're here to help, but you're expected to do the work. Manipulating arrays is stuff you'll need to know if you're going to be a programmer in any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you loop the array backwards you can build the array by making the new array = what the previous item was.

Then to merge the two arrays use array_merge_recursive.

```
$arr = ['level', 'sub', 'item'];
$arr = array_reverse($arr);
$new =[];

// Rebuild the array
foreach($arr as $key => $item){
    if($key ==0){
        $new = [$item => []];
    }else{
        $new = [$item => $new];
    }
}

// Your other array:
$other = array (
  'level' => 
  array (
    'sub' => 
    array (
      'AnotherItem' => 
      array (
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

// Merge the two
$new = array_merge_recursive($new, $other);

var_export($new);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'level' => 
  array (
    'sub' => 
    array (
      'item' => 
      array (
      ),
      'AnotherItem' => 
      array (
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

https://3v4l.org/VWBpM